# Cannot generate flextable output using kntr within Shiny app

Tags: r, flextable

Until recently I was using an older version of flextable (0.2.0) to generate a report from a shiny app that included a table of outputs.

To accommodate a change I needed to make I had to upgrade to 0.4.2.  Now the report no longer works.

The app throws this error:

```
**## Error in knit_print.flextable(x, ...): `render_flextable` needs to be used as a renderer for a knitr/rmarkdown R code chunk**
```

results of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_0.5.0           purrr_0.2.2           readr_1.0.0           tidyr_0.6.0          
 [5] tibble_1.2            ggplot2_2.2.0         tidyverse_1.0.0       shinycssloaders_0.2.0
 [9] officer_0.2.1         flextable_0.4.2       lattice_0.20-34       knitr_1.15.1         
[13] shinythemes_1.1.1     magrittr_1.5          DT_0.2                shinyjs_0.8          
[17] shiny_1.0.5          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_1.0.0         Rcpp_0.12.15      highr_0.6         plyr_1.8.4       
 [5] R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.5.0     base64enc_0.1-3   tools_3.3.2      
 [9] digest_0.6.10     packrat_0.4.8-1   uuid_0.1-2        jsonlite_1.1     
[13] evaluate_0.10     gtable_0.2.0      DBI_0.5-1         yaml_2.1.14      
[17] stringr_1.1.0     xml2_1.1.1        sourcetools_0.1.5 gdtools_0.1.6    
[21] htmlwidgets_0.8   rprojroot_1.1     grid_3.3.2        glue_1.2.0       
[25] R6_2.2.0          rmarkdown_1.8     scales_0.4.1      backports_1.0.4  
[29] htmltools_0.3.5   assertthat_0.1    colorspace_1.3-1  mime_0.5         
[33] xtable_1.8-2      httpuv_1.3.5      stringi_1.1.2     miniUI_0.1.1     
[37] lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     markdown_0.7.7    R.oo_1.21.0
```

Working example that displays the error:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),  

    mainPanel(
     fluidRow(
        QA_HTMLInput("QA_HTML1") 
      )
    )
  )
)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #browser()  

  rprtVec <- reactive({
    if(input$submit > 0) {
      x <- list(a=1,
                b=1,
                c=1,
                d=1,
                e=1,
                f=1,
                g=1,
                h=1,
                i=1,
                j=1,
                k=1,
                l=1,
                m=1,
                gg=1,
                hh=1,
                jj=1,
                mm=1,
                nn=1
      )
      x
    }
  }) 

  ###      

  HTMLRep1 <- observe({
      if(input$submit > 0) {
        callModule(QA_HTMLOption,"QA_HTML1",rprtVec(),"summaryQA.Rmd")
      }
  })

  })
```

global.R:

```
QA_HTMLInput <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  # tagList(
  #   tags$hr(style="border-color: darkblue;"),
  uiOutput(ns("report"))
  # )
}

# module server for Q HTML Report

QA_HTMLOption <- function(input, output, session, myvec, reportName) {

  output$report <- renderUI({

    ns <- session$ns

    # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
    # permission to the current working directory

    lbl <- substr(reportName,7,8)

    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(),reportName)
    try(file.copy(reportName,tempReport,overwrite = TRUE))

    # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document

    if(lbl == "QA"){
      params <- list(Title = myvec$a,
                     Author = myvec$b,
                     Date = myvec$c,
                     AR = myvec$d,
                     P10 = myvec$e,
                     OID = myvec$f,
                     OIO = myvec$g,
                     DID = myvec$h,
                     DIO = myvec$i,
                     IID = myvec$j,
                     IIO = myvec$k,
                     lkMtrx = myvec$l,
                     rskMtrx = myvec$m,
                     OCC = myvec$gg,
                     DET = myvec$hh,
                     LCS = myvec$jj,
                     MTX = myvec$mm,
                     RM1 = myvec$nn
      )
    }


    tagList(
      HTML(knitr::knit2html(text = readLines(tempReport), fragment.only = TRUE))
    )
  })

  return(list(
    #    Charact = reactive({input$charact})
  ))
}
```

Now the document to be knitted - summaryQA.Rmd:

````
---

---

<h2> 2. Summary: </h2>

For the <b> Quick Assessment </b>, the questions, with selected answers and associated scores are shown here.  These form the basis for the analysis.


```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}

library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

ID <- c("C01"," "," ","C02"," "," ","C03"," "," ")
Data <- c("Problem 1","Answer 1","Note 1","Problem 2","Answer 2","Note 2","Problem 3","Answer 3","Note 3")
Rank <- c("L"," "," ","L"," "," ","L"," "," ")
finalResults <- data.frame(ID,Data,Rank)

results_table1 <- flextable(finalResults) %>%
        theme_box() %>%

        ### Column Headers

        #  format column headers for table

        bold(part = "header") %>%
        fontsize(part = "header",size = 18) %>%
        align(part="header",align="center") %>%

        ### Body  

        # set column widths

        width(j =  ~ID, width = 1) %>%
        width(j =  ~Data, width = 8) %>%
        width(j =  ~Rank, width = 1) %>%

        # format general body of table

        fontsize(part = "body",size = 18) %>%
        align(j = ~ID, align = "center", part = "body") %>%
        align(j = ~Data, align = "left", part = "body") %>%
        align(j = ~Rank, align = "center", part = "body") %>%
        padding( padding = 5, part = "all" ) %>%
        style(pr_c = fp_cell(border = fp_border(color="black", width = 2)),part = "all") #%>%

      # format cell merging

      for(mm in seq(from=1,to=(nrow(finalResults)-2),by=3)) {
        results_table1 <- merge_at(results_table1,i=mm:(mm+2), j = ~ID, part = "body")
        results_table1 <- merge_at(results_table1,i=mm:(mm+2), j = ~Rank, part = "body")
      }

      results_table1

```
````

To correct this I have tried to use htmltools_value(), but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `QA_HTMLOption`, replace

```
tagList(
  HTML(knitr::knit2html(text = readLines(tempReport), fragment.only = TRUE))
)
```

by

```
temp_html <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
rmarkdown::render(input = tempReport, output_file = temp_html)
tagList(
  includeHTML(temp_html)
)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Two questions:  1) where can I read something that explains why your answer works and how to think about this kind of problem in the future.  2)  The app also generates a PDF using flextable 0.2.0.  Will I be able to do this with the new version?

Comment: 1/ rmarkdown is expected, the error need to be rewritten more clearly, sorry, I will see if I can support knitr::knit2html again. 2/ I am not sure I understand, flextable has never been able to generate pdf.

Comment: When using tabwid, I was able to create the flextable in the shiny app, store it as a reactive variable I created called values$... then execute that in a codeblock where a pdf was the target.  That worked really well.  That wasy I only had to generate the table once and use in the pdfs and html display.  But I have been trying to make the same idea work in the html with the new version and it appears that I cannot.  However I can regenerate the whole table in the codeblock for html and that works

Comment: Just haven't gotten to try the pdf files again.  I need the pdf report since the user can store it as an 'stable historical' copy of their results.  We do not want word documents since they can easily be edited by anyone.

Comment: Here is an example for shiny: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/examples.html#using-within-shiny-applications

Comment: IT works in Shiny, now that I have the new release installed and correctly setup.  One tab of the Shiny app shows an HTML report, with a button to make a PDF copy.

Comment: Any chance I could get the tabwid turned back on, even if you hide it?  if I generated a flextable in server.R and passed it into the pdf .Rmd, then use flextable::tabwid(MTX) in the codeblock I could display the table in a PDF.  I really need that functionality back.  It worked just fine!

Comment: WHen this call was used in a module (very much the same as about, and the yaml header was set for PDF, I got a flextable in the PDF document:

Comment: rmarkdown::render(tempReport, 
                        output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())